# Rails3: Is there a way to initialize a model with additional columns (calculated/aggregated) returned from a query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, join, rails-models

### THE SITUATION

So here's a simplified version of my situation:

I have a Payment model. It has the following attributes:

- Payment Amount
- Payment Date

I have a Transaction model. It has the following attributes:

- Transaction Description
- Transaction Amount
- Payment ID

NOTES:

- A payment can be applied to multiple transactions (i.e., a payment `has_many` transactions).
- A payment's remaining balance can be calculated by summing the transaction amounts of each transaction belonging to a payment.

I am currently calculating the remaining balance by using SQL join, group and the sum aggregation function. I added a scope to my Payment model to do this:

```
scope :all_with_balances, 
  select("payments.*, (payments.payment_amount - sum(transactions.transaction_amount) as remaining_balance").
  joins("LEFT JOIN transactions ON payments.id = transactions.payment_id").
  group(<list of payments columns>)
```

The important thing to note here is the additional column, `remaining_balance` being returned by this query, which is calculated as such: `(payments.payment_amount - sum(transactions.transaction_amount) as remaining_balance`.

### THE PROBLEM

Using this scope, Payment models are instantiated/initialized just fine with all the attributes that map to actual database columns. However, I would also like them to be initialized with the value of `remaining_balance`. **Is this possible?**

I thought I could do this defining an accessor for this column but it did not work.

```
attr_accessor :remaining_balance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord should attach attributes for all columns, including the computed ones, to the payment instances in the result set when you call the named scope:

```
payments = Payment.all_with_balances
balance = payments.first.remaining_balance # should be the value of the aggregate column
```

Is this not working?

Comment: Good grief! This is a classic example of RTFM. Thanks for the help! Would you be kind enough to point me to any resources that I can read more about this? I wasn't able to find it in either http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html or in the Edge Guides.

Comment: That's a good question. It's sort of implied in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html, section 2.5, where it says ActiveRecordBase#select ends up "initializing a model object with only the fields that you’ve selected", which shows AR is not simply returning an array of model instances as you might expect. It's also explained in better detail in Agile Web Development with Rails, 2nd Ed. in 19.3 "Advanced Attributes"

Comment: Ah. Yea guides.rubyonrails.org is a bit vague on this subject. I'll have to grab that book. Anyway, THANKS FOR THE HELP! This has been bugging me for the longest time. Thanks again!

Comment: Haha, I just realized you answered my other question the other night. The one about my typo `blank` vs. `blank?`.